# How do I stop leaking implementation details in my Azure Mobile app's OData errors?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile App Service.

Suppose I have a `Customer` entity, with an `Orders` navigation property. Then I can do this:

```
http://foo.url.com/tables/Customer?$expand=Orders
```

But suppose I try to expand a non-navigation property `Foo`:

```
http://foo.url.com/tables/Customer?$expand=Foo
```

Then I'll get this on the client (or Postman):

```
{
"message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Property 'Foo' on type 'my.namespace.Customer' is not a navigation property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.",
"exceptionMessage": "Property 'Foo' on type 'my.namespace.Customer' is not a navigation property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.",
"exceptionType": "Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException",
"stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SyntacticAst.ExpandBinder... VERY LONG STACKTRACE..."
}
```

Or suppose I try to expand non-existent property `Bar`:

```
http://foo.url.com/tables/Customer?$expand=Bar
```

Then I'll get this on the client (or Postman):

```
{
"message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'Bar' on type 'my.namespace.Customer'.",
"exceptionMessage": "Could not find a property named 'Bar' on type 'my.namespace.Customer'.",
"exceptionType": "Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException",
"stackTrace": "   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SyntacticAst.ExpandBinder... VERY LONG STACKTRACE"
}
```

If I edit the config to include `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Never` then it still leaks the namespace in this error (also it encourages the attacker to perform an enumeration attack and try all kinds of permutations):

```
{
"message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Property 'Foo' on type 'my.namespace.Customer' is not a navigation property. Only navigation properties can be expanded."
}
```

and

```
{
"message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'Bar' on type 'my.namespace.Customer'."
}
```

This leaks lots of implementation details which are interesting to an attacker. How do I suppress/replace that error message?

Comment: I wouldn't say it creates an attack vector, but it does leak information an attacker could find interesting. The solution of course is to catch and re-raise exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(answer updated with new info)

It turns out that this happens with Web API by itself, and the standard  `ExceptionFilter` and `ExceptionHandler` mechanisms don't seem to work.

One thing that does seem to work for rewriting the response if you get a 400 is the following:

```
public class MyExceptionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            actionExecutedContext.Response.Content = new StringContent("An error occurred.");
        }
    }
}
```

There's probably a better way than this.

Comment: I used the official "quickstart" from Azure, [I think this is the one](http://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/backend/dotnet/Quickstart/ZUMOAPPNAMEService). There is no `IncludeErrorDetailPolicy` in there, so in `Startup.ConfigureMobileApp()` I added `cfg.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Never`, but that still leaks some data (the full namespace) even though the stacktrace is now gone. I'm looking into the SDK's code to see where this happens, but haven't found anything so far, so maybe this is a WebAPI problem and an SDK problem?

Comment: Updated my question with more info. I'm thinking that this is a WebAPI problem rather than a "Zumo" problem, but then again, the error message discusses expanding of properties, which is a Zumo thing. Unsure.

Comment: Expand is a Web API/OData/Entity Framework thing, not specific to Zumo at all. However, it's possible that there is some default configuration that's getting applied. I'll check with some people who have more expertise and get back to you.

Comment: I added another idea, but I'd recommend posting a new question to narrow this down to just OData by itself, and tag it asp.net, and see if you get someone with specific expertise on that.

Comment: Yes that sounds like a good idea, thank you for looking into this!